# How is $i\int \cosh^2u\sinh^2udu = -\int \cos^2u\sin^2udu$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$I substituted $x=\cosh u$, thus $dx=\sinh udu$. Thus the integral becomes $\int \cosh^2u\sqrt{-\sinh^2u}\sinh udu = i\int \cosh^2u\sinh^2udu$

Another substitution I made to the original integral was $x = \cos u$, thus $dx=-\sin udu$. So the integral becomes $-\int \cos^2u\sqrt{\sin^2u}\sin udu = -\int \cos^2u\sin^2udu$

Thus would mean $i\int \cosh^2u\sinh^2udu = -\int \cos^2u\sin^2udu$, which graphically, I'm having a hard time believing. Can anyone clear me up?

Comment: You can't make the substitution $x=\cosh(u)$. The integrand is only defined for $|x|\leq 1$, but $\cosh(x)\geq 1$ for all real $x$.

Comment: That's why you churn out $i$ in the process, so even if there's a negative inside the root, there would be an $i$ to make it real, right?

Comment: It's not that simple. When you "evaluate" $\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, what you're doing is finding a *real* function whose derivative is $x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}$, so complex numbers should not appear in the process.

Comment: Both integrals in the title are elementary real integrals, leading to certain families $F(u)+C$, $\>G(u)+C'$. The factor $i$ in your formula obviously makes no sense, and omitting it does not make things correct.

Comment: the integrals are equal "algebraically" using $$\begin{align}
  & \sin \left( iz \right)=i\sinh \left( z \right) \\ 
 & \cos \left( iz \right)=\cosh \left( z \right) \\ 
\end{align}$$